# RecyclerView with multiple ViewHolder types

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In `GalleryFragment` I'm showing all images from the user gallery and I have a button at position 0, The button can do take new images via the camera.

I'm passing the first data in the list like this `galleryModelList.add(new GalleryModel(null, null, null));`

I did that because I want to show the button firstly then show else images.

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<GalleryModel> galleryModelList;

    public GalleryAdapter(List<GalleryModel> galleryModelList) {
        this.galleryModelList = galleryModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == 0)
            return new NewImageViewHolder(RowNewImageBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
        else
            return new GalleryViewHolder(RowGalleryBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == 0) {
            //...
        } else {
            //...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return galleryModelList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class NewImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RowNewImageBinding rowNewImageBinding;

        public NewImageViewHolder(@NonNull RowNewImageBinding rowNewImageBinding) {
            super(rowNewImageBinding.getRoot());
            this.rowNewImageBinding = rowNewImageBinding;
        }

    }

    public static class GalleryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RowGalleryBinding rowGalleryBinding;

        public GalleryViewHolder(@NonNull RowGalleryBinding rowGalleryBinding) {
            super(rowGalleryBinding.getRoot());
            this.rowGalleryBinding = rowGalleryBinding;
        }

    }

}
```

Everything works well but I want to ask is it a good way to pass null values to the first position like what I did above or there is a better way to show the button without passing fake data?

---

**Edit 16/02/2022**

The answer of [snachmsm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4217682/snachmsm) is correct but I made some changes and here is the result

[image]

When I click on the item next to the button, I'm getting this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.app.adapters.GalleryAdapter$NewImageViewHolder cannot be cast to com.test.app.adapters.GalleryAdapter$GalleryViewHolder`

**The error comes from here**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
    if (payloads.isEmpty())
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
    else
        ((GalleryViewHolder) holder).rowGalleryBinding.rowGalleryCounter.setText(String.valueOf(payloads.get(0)));
}
```

**Here is the full GalleryAdapter file**

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<GalleryModel> galleryModelList;
    private final List<Integer> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public GalleryAdapter(List<GalleryModel> galleryModelList) {
        this.galleryModelList = galleryModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == 0)
            return new NewImageViewHolder(RowNewImageBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
        else
            return new GalleryViewHolder(RowGalleryBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == 0) {
            //soon
        } else {
            int realPosition = position - 1;
            GalleryViewHolder galleryViewHolder = (GalleryViewHolder) holder;
            galleryViewHolder.rowGalleryBinding.setGalleryModel(galleryModelList.get(realPosition));
            if (selectedItems.contains(realPosition)) {
                galleryViewHolder.rowGalleryBinding.rowGalleryCounter.setText(String.valueOf(selectedItems.indexOf(realPosition) + 1));
                galleryViewHolder.rowGalleryBinding.rowGalleryCounter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else
                galleryViewHolder.rowGalleryBinding.rowGalleryCounter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            galleryViewHolder.rowGalleryBinding.rowGalleryContainer.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if (selectedItems.contains(realPosition)) {
                    selectedItems.remove((Integer) realPosition);
                    galleryViewHolder.rowGalleryBinding.rowGalleryCounter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    selectedItems.add(realPosition);
                    galleryViewHolder.rowGalleryBinding.rowGalleryCounter.setText(String.valueOf(selectedItems.indexOf(realPosition) + 1));
                    galleryViewHolder.rowGalleryBinding.rowGalleryCounter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++)
                    notifyItemChanged(selectedItems.get(i), selectedItems.indexOf(selectedItems.get(i)) + 1);
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
        if (payloads.isEmpty())
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
        else
            ((GalleryViewHolder) holder).rowGalleryBinding.rowGalleryCounter.setText(String.valueOf(payloads.get(0)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return galleryModelList.size() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class NewImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RowNewImageBinding rowNewImageBinding;

        public NewImageViewHolder(@NonNull RowNewImageBinding rowNewImageBinding) {
            super(rowNewImageBinding.getRoot());
            this.rowNewImageBinding = rowNewImageBinding;
        }

    }

    public static class GalleryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RowGalleryBinding rowGalleryBinding;

        public GalleryViewHolder(@NonNull RowGalleryBinding rowGalleryBinding) {
            super(rowGalleryBinding.getRoot());
            this.rowGalleryBinding = rowGalleryBinding;
        }

    }

}
```

The answer below is working perfectly as I said previously but after I made some changes I faced the error above and I don't have any idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't do this that way, this single/first item isn't a collection member. don't add this dummy view, instead inform adapter that there is one extra item

```
private static final int EXTRA_ITEMS_ON_TOP = 1; // num of buttons

private static final int TYPE_BUTTON = 0;
private static final int TYPE_LIST_ITEM =1;

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return galleryModelList.size() + EXTRA_ITEMS_ON_TOP;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // return TYPE_BUTTON type first position(s)
    return position < EXTRA_ITEMS_ON_TOP ? TYPE_BUTTON  : TYPE_LIST_ITEM;
}
```

and inside `onBindViewHolder` just recalculate position

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder.getItemViewType() == TYPE_BUTTON) {
        //... position < EXTRA_ITEMS_ON_TOP, so 0 only in current config
    } else {
        int realPosition = position - EXTRA_ITEMS_ON_TOP;
        GalleryModel model = galleryModelList.get(realPosition);
        ...
    }
}
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_BUTTON)
        return new NewImageViewHolder(RowNewImageBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
    else
        return new GalleryViewHolder(RowGalleryBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
}
```

your current way is kind of workaround. it may work, but further you may want to obtain full list from adapter and you will get list with one extra item (dummy one) and as it is fulfilled with `null`s you may get some `NullPointerException`. for fixing this you will probably make some `if`, which complicates code in next place

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll test it and back to tell you the result.

Comment: check out my edit, you had more problems in your code (wrong `getItemViewType` per `position`). now you can change numer of "buttons" with changing just one param - `EXTRA_ITEMS_ON_TOP` (set to 0 will hide button, you can also set it to 7 and you will get 7 buttons when needed)

Comment: If you have any idea to modify the title of the question to make it more clear for people who have an issue like my problem and make it easy to find the question. Thank you again

Comment: very good approach! :) just add some info that you are looking for proper `type`s configuration for adapter, e.g. `RecyclerView with multiple ViewHolder types`

Comment: Could you look at my question again after I modified it?

Comment: sadly no, as this is brand new topic and this should be new question. with posted code related to click, which cause crash

Comment: Okay, I'll try to post a new question soon if I don't find the solution. Thanks for your help ❤️️